# Pass multiple dynamic values to converter WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, imultivalueconverter

I'm working in a `WPF` application where i'm using `telerik:RadGridView` in which i have to make a column `ReadOnly` on certain conditions. The conditions values is within the collection which binds to the `gridview` and also some values from the `ViewModel`.

//Xaml:

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource SimplifiedView}"  SelectedValueMemberPath="StatusId" DisplayMemberPath="StatusName" DataMemberBinding="{Binding StatusName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
   <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>   
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewCell}">
           <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MemberId, Converter={StaticResource IntBoolConverter}}" Value="False" >
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
              </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
   </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
</telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn>
```

I have to use pass the `MemberId` and other values which is in the `ViewModel` to the Converter and make some calculations which return a `boolean` value. Assigning the value to the `IsReadOnlyBinding` property of the `GridViewColumn` make it work.

//Static Array:

```
   <telerik:RadWindow.Resources>
      <x:Array x:Key="CustomValues" 
             Type="sys:String"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
            <sys:String>Yes</sys:String>
            <sys:String>No</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
  </telerik:RadWindow.Resources>

  IsReadOnly="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomValues}, Converter={StaticResource MultipleValueForReadOnly}}"
```

I have worked on the above code where the static values are passed as an array to the converter, but i need to send the dynamic values such as `MemberId,blnReadFlag,ItemName` to the converter.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: I think you are looking for MultiValueConverter. take a look here: http://www.codearsenal.net/2013/12/wpf-multibinding-example.html#.VgqPlOhVhBc

Comment: @sexta13: How can i apply for a gridviewcolumn IsReadOnlyBinding property? Can you please share a sample code?

Comment: together with MultiValueConverter, you need `MultiBinding` instead. Using them is simple enough, just a little search you'll understand how to set up the MultiBinding and code for the IMultiValueConverter class.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/isreadonlybinding-and-multibinding
As far as I can see you cannot use it with IsReadOnlyBinding. Ca you have the "calculated" value ? maybe concatenate in a string and them parse it in the converter